# Dynamic form with resizing in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, user-interface

As a learning project in C# .net I am re-creating a [Gnome 3 plugin](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1078/twitchlive-panel/) for seeing who of the streamers you follow on Twitch is live. I have the settings form done, I am now working on the interface that is viewed from a click on the taskbar.

[This is a rough image of what I want the interface to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswOJ.png) When two or more streamers are live the interface would add another block and resize the form vertically similar to the menu for selecting a Wifi network in Windows.

What would be the best way for me to complete this?

My current thought is to maybe create a custom control and just place those inside a FlowLayoutPanel with some kind of code to change the vertical size of the form to match the added entries. Maybe this can be done without a custom control and be done with code inside a FlowLayoutPanel? I'm not too sure.

Ideally I would also have a click event in the panel for each streamer so I could then open a browser to their channel. A slight highlight would also be a plus (maybe change the background colour based on mouse hover).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You should try to create something first and come back with specific issues as you encounter them. You seem to have an idea already; Have you not tried it out? What are you struggling with?

Comment: @DangerZone I was mostly concerned with whether that idea (custom control) was good or not and what the best practices are for this situation. I don't really want to spend the time working on something only to find won't work and there was a better way from the beginning.